# Application of stoke's theorem to boundaries

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

[image]

I am having troubles from the last line. It says if form $\omega$ is exact then $\omega = dr$ I understand how they are using stoke's theorem however I don't understand why $$\int_{\partial S^1} r = 0$$ - could someone explain this please?

Answer (score 1):

Have you wondered what is actually the boundary of $S^1$?
$S^1$ is a closed one dimensional manifold. This means its boundary can only be a point (or a finite/numerable set of points). However, you have the extrema identification. So, you can say you don't have any extreme. All of this is a complicated way to say the circle has no boundary: the integral of any function on a zero measure space is zero.
$$\int_{\partial S^1} r = 0\, .$$

Comment: Alright say, we had a 2 dimensional unit sphere $S^2$ I don't see how the boundary of that is a clsoed one dimensional manifold - but $\int_{\partial S^2} r = 0$ too?

Comment: Yes. The surface of the 2-ball, which is the 2-sphere has no boundary, do you agree?

Comment: If you want you can see the $\partial$ operator as an analogous for the manifolds of the exterior derivative $\mathrm{d}$ on the forms. It is nihilpotent. 
This is related to something quite deep, that is a correspondence between topology and differential geometry, better, between homology and cohomology.